# CSS3: Creating Dots above a image without a div container

Tags: css

On the [website of Nintendo Online](http://nintendo-online.de/news/21459/super-smash-bros-mewtu-ab-sofort-verfuegbar) is a post image, which has little dots on it due to CSS. I would like to do this too, but without using a div container around the image.

Here is my current code:

```css
.image {
  background: url(http://nintendo-online.de/img/bg-game-header-cover.png) repeat;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://media2.giga.de/2013/06/osx_hero_2x.jpg" height="250" width="500px">
```

What do I have to change to make it visible? If I set z-index to 1 the image goes one stage up either. Is it even possible?

Comment: The Nintendo site uses two elements to achieve this. I'm not sure you will be able to do this with a single image element.

Comment: Background in under the image (element in general). Background can't be in higher layer than the element. If you use another element than `img`, you can use `:before/:after` pseudoclasses. They don't work with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:before` or `:after`

http://jsfiddle.net/omjo21mk/

```css
div {
  background: url(http://media2.giga.de/2013/06/osx_hero_2x.jpg) repeat;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
div:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://nintendo-online.de/img/bg-game-header-cover.png) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: But does not work with img tag or a class that was used by an image, huh?

Comment: :before and :after do not apply to the tag img

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple urls in the background css

```
.image {
  background: url(http://nintendo-online.de/img/bg-game-header-cover.png) repeat, url(http://media2.giga.de/2013/06/osx_hero_2x.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ae2jtpLn/1)

Comment: Would work, but I do not want to edit the html code. Dmitriys answer is a bit better, but thanks!